# How to concatenate variables into a query in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, t-sql

I am retrieving data in a monthly basis from 30 tables (each table represent a day). The query that I use for each individual table (day) is saved as a stored procedure and placed in a WHILE loop to run it for 30 days (run the query 30 times). I defined parameter A and B as time interval 3 PM and 7 PM because I would need to retrieve data for that period of time.

Below is the query (in the stored procedure) and it returns the value with no problem:

```
SELECT det_stn_id, SUM(vol) 
FROM <DBName>.<TBName> 
WHERE det_stn_id IN (36)
  AND userdatetime BETWEEN "2021-09-01 15:00:00" AND "2021-09-01 19:00:00"
```

Below is the query with variables A and B (in the stored procedure) and it doesn’t return any value:

```
set @A = SUBSTRING(@DataDate, 1, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@DataDate,5, 2) + '-' 
         + SUBSTRING(@DataDate, 7, 2) + ' ' + '15:00:00'

set @B = SUBSTRING(@DataDate, 1, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@DataDate,5, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@DataDate, 7, 2) + ' ' + '19:00:00'
print @A
print @B

SELECT det_stn_id, SUM(vol) FROM <DBName>.<TBName>
 where det_stn_id in (36)
 AND userdatetime BETWEEN @A AND @B'
```

Am I not properly concatenating variables A and B into the string? ( by the way, print @A and print @B returns the values I am trying to place into the strings which are “2021-09-01 15:00:00” and “2021-09-01 19:00:00”)

Comment: SQL Server and MySQL are completely different products; what are you *really* using?

Comment: What are the data types of `@A` `@B` and `@DataDate`? You could just do one query (no `while` loop) with `userdatetime >= @startDate AND userdatetime < @endDatePlus1 AND CAST(userdatetime AS time) >= CAST('15:00:00' as time) AND CAST(userdatetime AS time) <= CAST('19:00:00' as time)`

Answer (score 0):

mysql doesn't support + for characters, you need to `CONCAT`

> ```
> SET @DataDate = '20210101'
> ```

> ```
> set @A = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(@DataDate, 1, 4) , '-' , SUBSTRING(@DataDate,5, 2) , '-' 
>          , SUBSTRING(@DataDate, 7, 2) , ' ' , '15:00:00');
>
> set @B = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(@DataDate, 1, 4) , '-' , SUBSTRING(@DataDate,5, 2) , '-' , SUBSTRING(@DataDate, 7, 2) , ' ' , '19:00:00');
> SELECT @A;
> SELECT @B;
>
> SELECT det_stn_id, SUM(vol) FROM <DBName>.<TBName>
>  where det_stn_id in (36)
>  AND userdatetime BETWEEN @A AND @B'
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> | @A                  |
> | :------------------ |
> | 2021-01-01 15:00:00 |
>
> | @B                  |
> | :------------------ |
> | 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0d3ab20bff8e5951b72638cab937f59e)*

Also in sQL server you can use CONCAT

> ```
> CREATE TABLe TBName(det_stn_id INTEGER , vol INTEGER , userdatetime DATETIME)
> GO
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO TBName VALUEs (36,1, '20210101 16:00:00'),(36,1, '20210101 12:00:00')
> ,(36,2, '20210101 19:00:01')
> GO
> ```

> ```
> DECLARE @DataDate NVARCHAR(50)
> DECLARE @B DATETIME 
> DECLARE @A DATETIME 
> SET @DataDate = '20210101'
>
> set @A = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(@DataDate, 1, 4) , '-' , SUBSTRING(@DataDate,5, 2) , '-' 
>          , SUBSTRING(@DataDate, 7, 2) , ' ' , '15:00:00')
>
> set @B = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(@DataDate, 1, 4) , '-' , SUBSTRING(@DataDate,5, 2) , '-' 
> , SUBSTRING(@DataDate, 7, 2) , ' ' , '19:00:00')
>
>
> SELECT det_stn_id, SUM(vol) FROM TBName
>  where det_stn_id in (36)
>  AND userdatetime BETWEEN @A AND @B
>  GROUP BY det_stn_id
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> det_stn_id | (No column name)
> ---------: | ---------------:
>         36 |                1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=73ece342312b11bef1a618eb928753ad)*

Comment: Actually, I am using MS SQL Server Management Studio and it does return the values A and B (when I use "print @A" and "print @B" I can see the values).

Comment: The problem that I have is when I placed variables A and B in the stored procedure (the query), it does not return the query result, which is the summation of volume between time 3 and 7 pm.

Comment: the problem is in this part of the code:  '''AND userdatetime BETWEEN @A AND @B''''

Comment: pklease use this fiddle as start and enter some dates https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=37e97fbc0392a5cd71839c80007f9037

Comment: @Ash made a fiddle that shows you that it should work

Comment: @nbk you really shouldn't be quoting code or results. The question guide is quite clear about this. Quoting is for material which is being "quoted" from another source. I helpfully removed it for you, but I see you have rolled back those changes.

Comment: yes @DaleK i removed already twice your changes, as they don't improve anything, and i like it that way. so don't change it

Comment: @nbk just so you know you are using the quote incorrectly as per the site guidelines